# How can i Query sum like this

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a query Like this

```
  SELECT a.code ,a.group ,a.Desc ,
         Sum(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),a.amount)) 'BYDESC'
    FROM table1 as a
   WHERE a.Bol = 'Y'
GROUP BY a.code,a.group,a.Desc
ORDER BY a.code 
         Asc ,a.group asc ,a.Desc asc
```

and it gives me a table like this

```
CODE   GROUP  DESC        BYDESC
--------------------------------
G001   00001  D001          15.0
G001   00001  D002           3.0
G001   00001  D003         354.0
G001   00002  D001          27.0
   .       .     .             .
   .       .     .             .
   .       .     .             .
--------------------------------
```

I would like to sum each group and display like this

```
CODE   GROUP  DESC        BYDESC  Sum(BYGROUP)
---------------------------------------------
G001   00001  D001          15.0        372.0
G001   00001  D002           3.0        372.0
G001   00001  D003         354.0        372.0
G001   00002  D001          27.0         27.0
   .       .     .             .            .
   .       .     .             .            . 
   .       .     .             .            .
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression to achieve this.
Try this.

```
;with sumTable 
AS
( 
        SELECT a.code ,a.group ,Sum(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),a.amount)) SUMBYGROUP
          FROM table1 as a
          WHERE a.Bol = 'Y'
       GROUP BY a.code,a.group

)
  SELECT a.code ,a.group ,a.Desc ,Sum(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),a.amount)) 'BYDESC', sumTable.SUMBYGROUP as 'Sum(BYGROUP)'
    FROM table1 as a
    JOIN sumTable 
      ON (
          sumTable.code = a.code And sumTable.group = a.group 
         )
   WHERE a.Bol = 'Y'
GROUP BY a.code,a.group,a.Desc, sumTable.SUMBYGROUP
ORDER BY a.code asc ,a.group asc ,a.Desc asc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
After I tried this , I get this following error  - >
Column 'sumTable.SUMBYGROUP' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Izle I've edited my answer, you can give it a try now.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with GroupedTable 
AS
( 
    SELECT a.[COL1] ,a.[COL2] ,a.[COL3] ,Sum(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),a.[COL4])) 
     'BYDESC'
    FROM MyTable as a
    GROUP BY a.[COL1],a.[COL2],a.[COL3] 
)

SELECT 
    a.[COL1] ,a.[COL2] , a.[COL3] 
    ,Sum(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),a.[COL4])) 'BYDESC', mt.SUM
FROM MyTable as a
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT gt.[COL1] ,gt.[COL2] ,Sum(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),gt.[BYDESC])) AS 'SUM'
  FROM GroupedTable as gt
  GROUP BY gt.[COL1] ,gt.[COL2] 
) mt ON mt.[COL1] = a.[COL1] AND mt.[COL2] = a.[COL2]
GROUP BY a.[COL1],a.[COL2],a.[COL3], mt.SUM
ORDER BY  a.[COL1],a.[COL2],a.[COL3], mt.SUM
```

**[DB Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fcd17/55)**

Answer (score 1):

u can use windows function to acheive this.

```
with cte as
   (SELECT a.code,
        a.group,
        a.Desc,
        Sum(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),a.amount)) 'BYDESC'
        FROM table1 as a
        WHERE a.Bol = 'Y'
        GROUP BY a.code,a.group,a.Desc
       ) 
select *, 
sum(bydesc) over (partition by [group] order by [desc]
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    from cte
ORDER BY code Asc ,[group] asc , [Desc] asc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tested your solution but it seems like the result of last two column is a little bit weird  :(

Comment: hey izle, can you be a little more clear about the issue faced.

Comment: Well, First I face this following error "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views" , So I moved the order by and put it in the last line of my query and the result shown me that the sum of "sum(bydesc) over (partition by CallGroup order by CallDesc)" isn't correct

Comment: sorry missed out the range condition. please check the updated query.